# Execute Python Script as Root (seteuid vs c-wrapper)

Tags: python, c, django, freebsd

I have a quick one off task in a python script that I'd like to call from Django (www user), that's going to need to root privileges.

At first I thought I would could use Python's os.seteuid() and set the setuid bit on the script, but then I realized that I would have to set the setuid bit on Python itself, which I assume is big no no. From what I can tell, this would also be the case if using sudo, which I really would like to avoid.

At this point, I'm considering just writing a C wrapper the uses seteuid and calls my python script as root, passing the necessary arguments to it.

Is this the correct thing to do or should I be looking at something else?

Comment: Why don't you just execute it as an external process using `subprocess` and `sudo`, even though everything about this smells rotten.

Comment: Because that would require giving www permission to run Python as root :(

Comment: The primary issue here being that setuid and common sudo operations don't apply to individual python scripts as they would a binary, but rather the Python interpreter itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sudo does not require setuid bit on Python. You can enable sudo for one command only, no arguments:

```
 www          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:  /root/bin/reload-stuff.py ""
```

This would be secure if your script does not take any arguments, cannot be overridden by www user, and sudo does "env_reset" (the default in most distros).

You can accept arguments, but be very careful with them -- do not take output filenames, make sure you verify all inputs. In this case, remove "" from the end of sudo line.

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to test this immediately then. However, my script does take arguments, albeit simple ones. Do you think I would be ok as long as my python script is doing strict matching on these arguments?

Comment: yes. You can take agrumnts as long as you are careful with them.

Comment: `ALL=(root)` is probably preferred to limit running the script to only root, and not any other user. Better to limit to only what you need.

Comment: @theamk Is env_reset enough to prevent a user from loading his own site-packages and thus fooling `reload-stuff` into running malicious code? I'm particularly concerned regarding virtualenv or [PEP-370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)

Comment: env_reset will set HOME to target user's home (so /root, for example) and clear out all other environment -- so yes, virtualenvs would be ignored, and user site will be used from root's home, which will be secure

Answer (score 3):

The correct thing is called privilege separation: clearly identify minimal set of tasks which have to be done on elevated privileges. Write a separate daemon and an as much limited as possible way of communicating the task to do. Run this daemon as another user with elevated privileges. A bit more work, but also more secure.

EDIT: using a setuid-able wrapper will also satisfy the concept of privilege separation, although I recommend having the web server chrooted and mounting the chrooted file system nosuid (which would defeat that).

Comment: This is what I'm proposing using a C wrapper binary. It provides a limited interface to the specific functions the user needs access to with elevated privileges via seteuid().

Comment: Yes, you're right, that will do. I didn't consider it, because I recommend chrooting web servers and mounting the to the web server accessible file systems nosuid.

Comment: I'd like to recommend sudo over C wrapper. It is very easy to forget to clear, say, PYTHONSTARTUP, or some other env variable -- but sudo with env_reset will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` allows you to limit arguments passed to the program. From `man sudoers`:

```
john           ALPHA = /usr/bin/su [!-]*, !/usr/bin/su *root*

On the ALPHA machines, user john may su to anyone except root but
he is not allowed to specify any options to the su(1) command.
```

So use sudo. Of course you need to be extra careful with root access – make sure only root can modify the script itself and any parent directories, and that the script is safe and only does the absolute minimum that needs to be run as root.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this still requires giving the www user sudo root access to the Python interpreter itself, and you're essentially using sudo's argument parser to only allow your script to be run. Is this correct? If so, would it be easy to also account for arguments being passed to the script (key/values)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And yes, it should be easy, but I'd recommend communicating via stdin/stdout. Unfortunately, this being a security question, there's really no alternative to reading `man sudoers`.